# Sudoku solver in C not working properly

Tags: c, sudoku

I've written this Sudoku solver in C. But it isn't working properly, Any help?

With a sample input such as

```
1 0 3 4 0 0 7 0 9
0 5 6 0 8 9 0 2 3
0 8 9 1 0 3 4 0 6
2 1 4 0 6 5 0 9 7
3 0 0 8 0 7 0 1 4
8 0 7 0 1 4 0 6 5
0 3 1 0 4 0 9 7 8
6 4 0 9 7 0 5 3 1
0 7 8 0 0 1 0 4 2
```

it gives output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
7 5 6 0 8 9 1 2 3 
0 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 
2 1 4 3 6 5 8 9 7 
3 9 5 8 0 7 2 1 4 
8 0 7 2 1 4 3 6 5 
5 3 1 6 4 2 9 7 8 
6 4 2 9 7 8 5 3 1 
9 7 8 5 3 1 6 4 2
```

Any idea what went wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sudoku[9][9];

int check(int sudoku[][9], int row, int col, int sol)
{
    //checking in the grid
    int row_grid = (row/3) * 3;
    int col_grid = (col/3) * 3;

    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<9; ++i)
    {
        if (sudoku[row][i] == sol)                             
            return 0;
        if (sudoku[i][col] == sol)                             
            return 0;
        if (sudoku[row_grid + (i%3)][col_grid + (i/3)] == sol) 
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}  


int main(void)
{
    int i,j,k;
    printf("enter the sudoku and enter 0 for unknown entries \n");
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&sudoku[i][j]);
        }
    }    
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            if(sudoku[i][j]==0)
            {
                for (k=1;k<=9;k++)
                {
                    if(check(sudoku,i,j,k)==1)
                    {
                        sudoku[i][j] = k;                   
                    }
                }               
            }
        }
    }

    printf("solved sudoku \n");
    for(i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<9;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", sudoku[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you attempted to debug the code yourself?

Comment: yeah, could not find a clue. That is why I am posting it in here

Comment: show your intend, logic, and what you expect for output.

Comment: [Try to narrow down the problem by debugging your code](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/how-to-ask-for-programming-help/). This process should help you find the bug on your own. If you still can't find it after narrowing it down, other people can help you much more easily.

Comment: Your loops should probably be running `for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)`; the `check()` code won't calculate the `row_grid` and `col_grid` values accurately if you run from 1 to 9 instead of 0 to 8.

Comment: I am running 
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++);

Comment: I want to solve any given sudoku, using a simple brute force way. I am checking row, coloumn and grid, any filling values accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to solve a sudoku this way. You just loop through all cells and for each empty cell you pick the biggest value that can be there. Obviously, it is incorrect, since there might be several variants in one cell. And you always pick the biggest (since there is no `break` in a `for (k=...)` loop).
Sometimes you pick the wrong number and it makes a sudoku inconsistent.

UPDATE: what you do is not a brute-force, since you don't iterate through all possible solutions.
Instead of

```
if(check(sudoku,i,j,k)==1)
{
    sudoku[i][j] = k;                   
}
```

There must be something like

```
if(check(sudoku,i,j,k)==1)
{
    tempSudoku = copy(sudoku); //pseudocode
    tempSudoku[i][j] = k;
    tryToSolveRecursively(tempSudoku);              
}
```

If check() returned 0, then there is an inconsistency (for some empty cell we can't find a single possible solution). And so we should abandon this solution, go back and try something else (viva la recursion :) ).
This is not an only option, but I just hope that it will point you in a right direction.

P.S. Brute force solution based just on basic sudoku rules will be **terribly slow**. Trust me. You need additional heuristics to reduce the search space.

Comment: thanks man, any better way to do this, to get rid of the inconsistency??

Comment: @goromlagche, I updated an answer. Unfortunately, I can't provide links about solving sudoku, since all the links I have are in Russian :) But I guess that you can google several techniques.

Comment: @goromlagche, this might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238114/Realtime-Webcam-Sudoku-Solver